# Python: SQL Generated Variables written to HTML file

Tags: python, html, sql, file

I have a script in Python which connects to SQL using pyodbc and returns a set of values from a calendar for the 30 days following today. I prototyped it by using the print('') function to generate the HTML for the file I was creating then copying and pasting it in to an HTML file with Notepad++ and I know the HTML is sound and will be good for its purpose. However when it comes to generating the file I'm running aground with including the SQL results in the variable that is passed to the file writer.

I have tried both {variable} and %v methods which just seem to be either erroring out with;

```
unsupported format character ';' (0x3b) at index 1744
```

in the case of %, or in the case of {inset} is just including the word rather than the var. below is the code I have in JN;

```
from os import getenv
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=MYSERVER\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=MyTable;UID=test;PWD=t')

f = open('tes.html','w')

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('DECLARE @today as date SET @today = GetDate() SELECT style112, day, month, year, dayofweek, showroom_name, isbusy from ShowroomCal where Date Between @today and dateadd(month,1,@today) ')
row = cursor.fetchone()

while row is not None:
    inset = ('<div class="',row.isbusy,'"><a href="#" target="_self" title="',row.style112,'" onclick="updateValue(this.title, event);">',row.day,'</a></div>')
    row = cursor.fetchone()

html_str = """
<html lang="en" ><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Calendar</title>
<link rel=\'stylesheet prefetch\' href=\'https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css\'>
<style>
body{background-color: #ffffff;}
a{color:#462955; text-decoration: none; display: block;}a:hover{color:#ffffff; text-decoration: none; display: block;}#yes a {color:#ffffff !important; text-decoration: none; display: block;}#yes a:hover {color:#ffffff !important; text-decoration: none; display: block;}
#calendar{margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;width: 800px;font-family: \'Lato\', sans-serif;}
#calendar_weekdays div{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;}
#calendar_content, #calendar_weekdays, #calendar_header{position: relative;width: 800px;overflow: hidden;float: left;z-index: 10;}
#calendar_weekdays div, #calendar_content div{width: 25px;height: 25px;overflow: hidden;text-align: center;background-color: #FFFFFF;color: #787878;}
.Yes{background-color: #990000 !important;color: #CDCDCD !important;}
.None{background-color: #ffffff !Important;color: #462955 !important;}
.None:hover{background-color: #462955 !Important;color: #ffffff !important;}
.wend{background-color: #676767 !important;color: #999999 !important;}
#calendar_content{background-colour: #ff0000;-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 12px 12px;-moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 12px 12px; border-radius: 0px 0px 12px 12px;}
#calendar_content div{float: left;}
#yes {background-color: #ff0000 !important;}
#calendar_content div:hover{background-color: #F8F8F8;}
#calendar_content div.blank{background-color: #E8E8E8;}
#calendar_header, #calendar_content div.today{zoom: 1;filter: alpha(opacity=70);opacity: 0.7;}
#calendar_content div.today{color: #FFFFFF;}
#calendar_header{width: 100%;height: 25px;text-align: center;background-color: #FF6860;padding: 8px 0;-webkit-border-radius: 12px 12px 0px 0px;-moz-border-radius: 12px 12px 0px 0px; border-radius: 12px 12px 0px 0px;}
#calendar_header h1{font-size: 1.5em;color: #FFFFFF;float:left;width:70%;
i[class^=icon-chevron]{color: #FFFFFF;float: left;width:15%;border-radius: 50%;}
</style>
<link href=\'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato\' rel=\'stylesheet\' type=\'text/css\'>
</head><base target="_parent">
<div id="calendar"><div id="calendar_header"><h1>07 2018</h1></div><div id="calendar_weekdays"></div><div id="calendar_content">
{inset}
</div></div><script src=\'jquery.min.js\'></script>
<script>
$(function(){function c(){p();var e=h();var r=0;var u=false;l.empty();while(!u){if(s[r]==e[0].weekday){u=true}else{l.append(\'<div class="blank"></div>\');r++}}for(var c=0;c<42-r;c++){if(c>=e.length){l.append(\'<div class="blank"></div>\')}else{var v=e[c].day;var m=g(new Date(t,n-1,v))?\'<div class="today">\':"<div>";l.append(m+""+v+"</div>")}}var y=o[n-1];a.css("background-color",y).find("h1").text(i[n-1]+" "+t);f.find("div").css("color",y);l.find(".today").css("background-color",y);d()}function h(){var e=[];for(var r=1;r<v(t,n)+1;r++){e.push({day:r,weekday:s[m(t,n,r)]})}return e}function p(){f.empty();for(var e=0;e<7;e++){f.append("<div>"+s[e].substring(0,3)+"</div>")}}function d(){var t;var n=$("#calendar").css("width",e+"px");n.find(t="#calendar_weekdays, #calendar_content").css("width",e+"px").find("div").css({width:e/7+"px",height:e/14+"px","line-height":e/14+"px"});n.find("#calendar_header").css({height:e*(1/14)+"px"}).find(\'i[class^="icon-chevron"]\').css("line-height",e*(1/14)+"px")}function v(e,t){return(new Date(e,t,0)).getDate()}function m(e,t,n){return(new Date(e,t-1,n)).getDay()}function g(e){return y(new Date)==y(e)}function y(e){return e.getFullYear()+"/"+(e.getMonth()+1)+"/"+e.getDate()}function b(){var e=new Date;t=e.getFullYear();n=e.getMonth()+1}var e=700;var t=2018;var n=9;var r=[];var i=["JANUARY","FEBRUARY","MARCH","APRIL","MAY","JUNE","JULY","AUGUST","SEPTEMBER","OCTOBER","NOVEMBER","DECEMBER"];var s=["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];var o=["#462955","#462955","#462955","#462955","#462955","#462955","#462955","#462955","#462955","#462955","#462955","#462955"];var u=$("#calendar");var a=u.find("#calendar_header");var f=u.find("#calendarweekdays");var l=u.find("#calendarcontent");b();c();a.find(\'i[class^="icon-chevron"]\').on("click",function(){var e=$(this);var r=function(e){n=e=="next"?n+1:n-1;if(n<1){n=12;t--}else if(n>12){n=1;t++}c()};if(e.attr("class").indexOf("left")!=-1){r("previous")}else{r("next")}})})
function updateValue(val, event) {document.getElementById("field17").value = val;event.preventDefault();}
</script>
</body></html><wehavechangedit>
"""

cnxn.close()

f.write(html_str)
f.close()
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of a better way to include the variables? Do I need to have the inset as an array for this model?

It's Py3.6, on Windows 10.

Comment: The issue is that all of Python's string interpolation methods collide with parts of your HTML string that are supposed to be static. You might want to look a template engines. There are many different options just for HTML templating that take care of the potential collisions for you. [Jinja 2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) for example. But maybe you prefer something even more lightweight. [Here's](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating) what I expect to be a pretty exhaustive list of engines available in Python

Comment: Thank you, I'll look in to Jinja2 this afternoon and try it out tomorrow morning for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to just save your html_str inside a template .html file, write your inset lines into a long string, then read your file into a string, do the replace, then re-write the file?

```
 with open('C:\\template.html') as file:
      wholefile = file.readlines()
```

use this to make a string of your results.

```
 inset = inset + '<div class="'+ str(row.isbusy) + '"><a href="#" target="_self" title="' + str(row.style112) + '" onclick="updateValue(this.title, event);">' + str(row.day) + '</a></div>' + '\n'
```

and then do the replace, so you will have the complete file in a string, then write it back out.

```
wholefile.replace('{inset}',inset)
```